# Python text adventure - items interacting with the game world

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mildly long question, tl;dr at the bottom.

Quite the python beginner here. I am having *such* a frustrating time trying to get items to interact with the world in this text adventure. I can get the player to pick up items and trade items, however I can't get items to interact with the world. My goal: for a room to require an item in order for the player to continue. As of right now I don't need anything more complicated than just displaying different text, i.e. "The cell is locked. Find the key!" without the key in the inventory, and "You unlocked the cell!" with the key in the inventory. Eventually I'll require player input. I know this can be done with a simple "if item in inventory" statement, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My code for the room:

```
class GoalCell(MapTile):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.item = items.CellKey()
        self.have_key = False
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def modify_player(self, player):
        if self.item in player.inventory:
            self.have_key = True
            player.inventory.remove(self.item)
            print("Key used.") #I tried using this to see if this function was even running. Alas, it is not, and the statement does not show up.

    def intro_text(self):
        if self.have_key:
            return "\nYou unlock the cell with your key. Congratulations, you freed your uncle and won the game!"
        else:
            return "\nYou enter the cell of your derelict uncle. 'Hey, kid,' he rasps, 'you gotta get me out of here.' The key has to be here somewhere..."
```

(edited) My apologies, the code above does not return an error - it simply doesn't work. All that displays is the text "You enter the cell of your derelict uncle..." even when the key is in the player's inventory. The Player class being referenced:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
            self.inventory = [items.Fists(),
                              items.CellKey()]
            self.x = world.start_tile_location[0]
            self.y = world.start_tile_location[1]
            self.hp = 100
            self.money = 0
            self.victory = False
```

I have this line in the main game code, so the capitalization is not an issue:

```
player = Player()
```

And I have other rooms that use the 'player.inventory' call (to append items, to remove items, etc.) and those work just fine, like the very similar code below:

```
class FindWeaponTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.item = items.BrassKnuckles()
        self.item_claimed = False
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def modify_player(self, player):
        if not self.item_claimed:
            self.item_claimed = True
            player.inventory.append(self.item)
            print("Weapon added.")

    def intro_text(self):
        if self.item_claimed:
            return "\nAn empty area of the rec yard. Nowhere to turn but back the way you came."
        else:
            return "\nYou spot some brass knuckles on the ground!"
```

That code displays the correct text before/after the item is picked up and it appends the item to the player's inventory with no problem.

Eventually I want to make games with more complex 'lock-and-key' puzzles and it's bothering me that I can't do this simple example. Any and all help would be appreciated.

**Tl;dr** My room displays something like "The prison cell is locked. The key must be somewhere..." while the player does not have the key. When the player has the key, I want it to display "You unlocked the cell!" or whatever. Tried "if item in inventory" to no avail. Frustrated. Please. Help.

**Edit:**
Sorry, this might help. Main game function:

```
def play():
    print("Welcome to the Delaware County Correctional Facility!")
    world.parse_world_dsl()
    player = Player()
    while player.is_alive() and not player.victory:
        room = world.tile_at(player.x, player.y)
        print(room.intro_text())
        room.modify_player(player)
        if player.is_alive() and not player.victory:
            choose_action(room, player)
        elif not player.is_alive():
            print("The inmates got the best of you! Game over!")
```

**Edit:**
I'm so sorry, I edited the original question because the code I have displayed above does not give me an error. Definite mistake on my part. That error was taken care of. My issue is that the code flat-out doesn't work the way I want it to. All it returns is the intro text for when the player doesn't have the key (even when they do). It's as similar as I could make it to FindWeaponTile() code which works correctly.

Comment: Where/how are you calling `modify_player`?

Comment: A `Player` *module* does not have an inventory; a `Player` *object* does.   Or maybe I misunderstand what "a load of barnacles" means.

Comment: Well, your problem is quite obvious: the method you expect to be called is not. Continue with your `print` tracking, going back from your `print("key used")` call, and you'll find what is wrong.

Comment: Ooh Scott you have a point. A load of barnacles was simply me being facetious. Though I still don't get how the 'player.inventory' is being used correctly in another class (the FindWeaponTile) and not the GoalCell class. [I'm very, very new to OOP]

Comment: Still hard to see what the issue is if we don't have a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Posting a stack trace helps.

Comment: Oh my lordy Andrew I'm so sorry, thank you for asking for the stack trace. It hit me that the attribute error was an error I was getting with a previous attempt, not the attempt I have shown above. Question edited for clarity.

Comment: you have to use `room.modify_player(player)` before `print(room.intro_text())`

Comment: Just tried it, unfortunately it did not work. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using items.CellKey() itself I accessed it's name attribute (a string) and it worked. Thank you all for your help!